# How does this identity so elegantly combine an infinite sum in $\eta$ and an improper integral in $\Gamma$?

Tags: gamma-function, dirichlet-series, analytic-continuation

[image: First definition]

This is all well and good, but where did *this* come from?

[image: Other definition]

In the article on the Gamma function, Wikipedia shows most of its alternate definitions with clear proofs, yet in the article on the Dirichlet Eta function, this bizarre identity is just asserted with the phrase, "we may begin by defining: ". My calculus is not at all good enough to relate a $\Sigma$ sum to a $\int$ sum like this, but here Wikipedia's assertion seems to be that multiplying in the $\eta$ sum to the $\Gamma$ function adds one to the denominator of the integrand and I cannot for the life of me see why. A quick google search avails me nought, either.

Comment: You should never accept an answer that quickly. Maybe you are missing out on more detailed answers.

Comment: @vitamind fair point! It’s likely the Wikipedia article will be too dense for me. I’m hoping that someone might provide an intuition for the very very simple-seeming “+1” into the denominator of $\Gamma$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{s-1}e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t$ for any $s>0$.
From the geometrical series it follows that
$$ \frac{1}{1-(-e^x)} = \sum_{n\ge0}(-e^{-x})^{n}.$$
with uniform convergence over any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^+$.
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac {x^{s - 1} } {e^x + 1}\,\mathrm{d}x
 &= \int_0^\infty \frac {x^{s - 1} e^{-x} } {1 - ( {-e^{-x} }) } \,\mathrm{d} x \\
&= \int_0^\infty x^{s - 1} e^{-x} \left( {\sum_{n\ge0} ({-e^{-x} })^n} \,\mathrm{d} x\right)\\
&= \sum_{n \ge 0} \left( {( {-1})^n \int_0^\infty x^{s - 1} e^{- {(n + 1)} x} \,\mathrm{d} x}\right) \end{align}$$
Substitute $t=(n+1)x\Rightarrow \,\mathrm{d}x=1/(n+1)\,\mathrm{d}t$. The integral now becomes $\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{t}{n+1}\right)^{s-1} e^{- t}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{n+1}=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)^s} t^{s-1} e^{- t}\,\mathrm{d} t$. The first two factors can be written outside the integral, which leaves us with the Gamma function.
$$
\begin{align}
&= \Gamma (s) \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac {( {-1})^n} { ({n + 1})^s} \\
&= \Gamma (s) \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac {( {-1})^{n-1}} { n^s} \\
&= \Gamma(s) \, \eta(s)
\end{align}$$

Comment: The step that confuses me in all the answers so far is the factoring out of the (n+1) in the negative exponential to the $\frac{1}{(n+1)^s}$

Comment: @IdioticShrike Please say what line exactly. I then will elaborate.

Comment: line three of the integral expansion

Comment: @IdioticShrike From line 3 to 4? Try the substitution $t=x(n+1)$. I will include the steps in my answer.

Comment: that is genuinely beautiful, thank you. I think of all the questions I've asked on this site, this has been the most profound and patient answer I've ever received!

Comment: @IdioticShrike Thank you! I have included the whole substitution now.

Comment: I wonder: I've tried to prove the fact that all values of $\eta$ for an even negative input are zero using Abel sums, but I got absolutely nowhere in terms of a general proof. Could this definition of $\eta$ be manipulated to prove this? Although, the $\frac{1}{\Gamma}$ term would go to zero for negative integer input, since $\Gamma$ has poles at those values, yet something like $\eta(-3)\neq0$ - how might I resolve this dilemma?

Comment: @IdioticShrike Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123791/discussion-between-vitamin-d-and-idiotic-shrike).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#Zeta_Function) of the Wikipedia entry for "Mellin transform"; it shows the derivation of the analogous formula
$$
\zeta(s) = \frac1{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}\,dx,
$$
and the method works great for the desired $\eta(s)$ identity as well.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{e^x+1}=\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^ne^{-(n+1)x}$

Leads to $\eta(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int\limits_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-(n+1)x}dx=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s}$